# Windows 7: Migrate user profile from windows.old to new OS

Tags: windows-7

HI,
I recently crashed my computer and somehow I couldn't repair my Windows 7 installation so I decided to reinstall entire OS (Windows 7) of course my old system files were saved in Windows.old folder. But now I wonder if there is a way I can transfer my user profile from the old OS to new. Is there a way to transfer user profile from Windows.old to new OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in c:\users to see if your old profile exists there.  If it still exists then you can map it to your new account using [User Profile Manager](http://www.forensit.com/desktop-management.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but user profile is not in that specific folder it was moved along with other files into c:\windows.old\. I copied my old user profile folder into the current c:\Users and with User profile Manager I can see it if I check »show unassigned profiles«. I quickly checked the manual and I read that I can assign this “unassigned profile” to existing one and it seems that it works, I can see my certificates now I have to see if I can use my VPN connection to work network.
I wonder if this is the only way or I can make this ”unassigned profile”  part of local accounts?
B.r.

Comment: I managed to get my old installation back by following guide on this site http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/16282-windows-old-folder-restore-into-new-installation.html , I guess the damage to the system was not so hard since I have all my accounts back.  I just wanted to let you know.

Comment: above link is now 404